# eigen value of the gradient operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

Eigen value of the following differential equation

$$\nabla \phi (\vec r) = a  \vec {k} \phi(\vec{r})$$

is

$$ \phi(\vec{r}) = e^{a \vec{k}.\vec{r}}$$

How can i derive this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\R{{\bf r}}
\def\K{{\bf k}}
\def\o{\cdot}$The function $\phi(\R) = e^{a \K\o\R}$ is an *eigenfunction* of the differential *operator* $\nabla$ with *eigenvalue* $a\K$.
This can be shown by proving that 
$\nabla \phi(\R) = a\K \phi(\R)$ 
for the given $\phi(\R)$.

For the $x$-component
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla_x e^{a \K\o\R} &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\exp a (k_x x+ k_y y + k_z z) \\
&=& a k_x \exp a (k_x x+ k_y y + k_z z) \\
&=& a k_x e^{a \K\o\R}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The other components go similarly. 
The result follows.

Comment: thanks a lot. That does it. I will try to reconstruct this for spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Aftnix: Glad to help. Ask away if you have any trouble with that. :-)